How to configure django templates and webpack
I am using a django project created by django-cookiecutter template.I want to use webpack to bundle my js files (normal js) and css files..previously I used django-compressor to compress css files.
I am a newbie in webpack and I would like to ask the following direct questions

How do I configure my entry point to include all static files
How do I render bundled js files from form Media class

